# Chrome won't allow access to web address - how do I get Avast to allow?

Tags: google-chrome, avast

Using Windows 7, Avast anti-virus and Chrome.  Trying to log into my own website which is getting blocked by Avast antivirus saying malware. Others are able to log in on other PC's and via mobile.

Getting this message:

> This site can’t be reached, The connection was reset. Try: Checking the
>   connection, checking the proxy and the firewall.

And this:

> Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus
>   settings. If it is already listed as a program allowed to access the
>   network, try removing it from the list and adding it again.

How do I allow it and get Avast to stop blocking?

Answer (score 2):

#### How do I allow my website and get Avast to stop blocking?

Add your site to the Web Shield "Exclusions" list or disable Web Shield completely.

**To add an "Exclusion":**

1. Open "Avast Settings"
2. Click on "Active Protection"
3. Click the "Customise" link for "Web Shield"

   [image]
4. Click "Exclusions"
5. Add the URL for your website to "URL's to exclude"
6. Click "Add"

   [image]
7. Click "OK"
8. Click "OK" again

---

**To disable "Web Shield" completely:**

1. Open "Avast Settings"
2. Click on "Active Protection"
3. Click the "On" button for "Web Shield" to turn it off:

   - Select "Stop Permanently"
   - Click "Yes" on the popup warning dialog.

   [image]
4. Click "OK"

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to [accept my answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer). Thanks.